# Transfer speed much slower in Wi-Fi than Ethernet

Tags: wifi, performance, ethernet, nas

I'm transferring a lot of pictures from my Macbook Pro to a local Synology NAS (DS116), using an FTP software named Transmit.

I noticed that the upload speed is quite different between Wi-Fi and Ethernet:

- Using Wi-Fi (ac): ~27 MB/s in FTP mode, and ~22 MB/s in AFP mode
- Using Ethernet (via a Thunderbolt adapter): ~110 MB/s, in both FTP and AFP modes

I don't understand why the Wi-Fi transfers are so slow compared to Ethernet. Both of them should handle the maximum write speed of the disk (112 MB/s according to Synology).

Any idea about what could be slowing down the transfers when using Wi-Fi?

Notes about my Wi-Fi :

> RSSI: -56 dBm
>
> Noise: -95 dBm
>
> TX Rate: 350 Mbps
>
> PHY Mode: 802.11ac
>
> Router: TP-Link AC750

Comment: 350 Megabit per Second (Mbps) = 43.75 Megabyte per Second (MB/s). Ethernet is always faster then Wi-Fi.

Comment: What @pjc90 said.  Plus a wired connection will always be more reliable.

Comment: I know that it's always faster :) My assumption was actually that my router allowed 750 mbps = 93 MBps, given that it's named AC750. But after checking the specs of the router, it appears that 750 is the dual-band speed... And in my case, I'm using the 5 Ghz band which is limited to 433 mbps. Plus the noise, thus the 350 mbps.
So I guess the limitation comes from the router... I really thought it was faster!
Thanks for your answer ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it an official answer:

350 Megabit per Second (Mbps) = 43.75 Megabyte per Second (MB/s). Ethernet is always faster and more reliable then Wi-Fi. So when Ethernet is available, use it.